# Choosing random index from an array which will link to the same index of another array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, random

I acknowledge that the title seems very confusing, I was just unable to word it correctly, rest assured I will explain my problem in depth here.

I will first explain what I am wanting to accomplish as a whole.

I am wanting to create a program that will ask the user to guess the country name based on a displayed capital city. The user will now have the choice to enter up to three country names, in one line, each separated by a comma, displaying a warning if the user enters more than the three that are asked for. The program will then generate a random number between (0-5). The random number will be used as an index to retrieve both a capital city from the capital city array and the corresponding country name (which would be the correct answer).

I started trying to solve it, but I am just not sure what my best choice should be to generate a random number between 0-5 that links to the city and then link them to the corresponding country.

Any help would be appreciated If you need more information just ask.
I will post the code of what I have attempted below:

```
        string[] capitals = new string[] { "Athens", "Bangkok", "Beijing", "Berlin", "Amsterdam", "Ankara" };
        string[] countrynames = new string[] { "Greece", "Thailand", "China", "Germany", "Netherlands", "Turkey" };

        string random = capitals[new Random().Next(0, 5)];

        WriteLine("Which country has the capital city {0}? ", random);
        Write("Enter up to 3 names, comma-seperated: ");
        string userinput = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] temp = userinput.Split(',');
```

Comment: Whats wrong with this code and what is not working? The random part of the code looks good.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code Jaya, it executes fine, I am just wondering where I should go next to achieve what I am wanting to.

Comment: What do you want to do is my question? where are you stuck exactly? Is it that you are not able to parse user's answer? or what exactly? your question asked here seems to be specifiic to random number generation which looks right.

Comment: The call to `new Random().Next(0, 5)` generates a number between `0` and `4`. The second parameter is an **exclusive** upper-bound.

Comment: I want to create my desired program, that I explained above but I am not sure where I should go from here to achieve this. I have created the two arrays. Prompted for user input and read it as a string. I am wanting to take the random index from capitals and have it link to the correct index of countrynmes (the correct country of the random capital), then check it against the user's input to see if the correct answer has been entered.

Comment: Create a field-level variable `private random = new Random();`. Then you can do `int index = random.Next(0, capitals.Length);` to get a index that you can us in your program to reference the `countrynames` array to get your answer.

Comment: You might find `string[] temp = userinput.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToArray();` useful.

Comment: And `String.Compare(temp[0], countrynames[index], true)` might also be of interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just added to your code. Of course you need to handle errors if the user input is not comma separated and othewise. Just ensure to get that handled appropriately. It would be really appropriate if you have both country and capitals in a singular data structure such as a `dictionary`

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public static void Main()
{
    string[] capitals = new string[] { "Athens", "Bangkok", "Beijing", "Berlin", "Amsterdam", "Ankara" };
    string[] countrynames = new string[] { "Greece", "Thailand", "China", "Germany", "Netherlands", "Turkey" };

    var rand = new Random().Next(0, capitals.length); // assuming it can be more than 5
    string randomCapital = capitals[rand];
    var correspondingRandomCountry = countrynames[rand]; // assuming your country array is in the righ order

    Console.WriteLine("Which country has the capital city {0}? ", randomCapital);
    Console.WriteLine("Enter up to 3 names, comma-seperated: ");
    string userinput = Console.ReadLine();
    string[] temp = userinput.Split(',');
    var rightOrWrongString = temp.Any(t => t.ToLower().Equals(correspondingRandomCountry.ToLower())) == true ? "right answer" : "wrong answer";
    Console.WriteLine("total no: of guesses made {0} - Result: {1}", temp.length,  rightOrWrongString );


}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1NT1WS).

Comment: Awesome answer, its really helped me out. If I was to make sure that user input was for 3 values or under (three guesses at the country name), how would I implement that into your code? an if statement?

Comment: Glad it helped you. If so upvote the answer. The `length` of the temp array would give you the number of guesses. Edited the code above.

Answer (score 1):

Although you could do this by using a local variable to synchronize the index of the question, and answer, like this:

```
var randomIndex = new Random().Next(capitals.Length);
var capital = capitals[randomIndex];
var country = countrynames[randomIndex];

WriteLine("Which country has the capital city {0}? ", capital);
// code to check user input vs country goes here
```

To me, two independent arrays seems like the wrong tool for the job. Since there seems to be one answer per question, and the questions are unique, how about creating a map with a `Dictionary` (or at least keeping the questions and answers together with a `Tuple`, or simple `class`)?

```
var capitalCountryMap = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"Athens", "Greece"}, {"Bangkok", "Thailand"}, {"X", "Y"}
};

var randomIndex = new Random().Next(capitalCountryMap.Count);
var questionAnswer = capitalCountryMap.ElementAt(randomIndex);
```

You'll then ask question with `questionAnswer.Key` and compare the user's input to `questionAnswer.Value`

The benefit of keeping data together like this is that it will become difficult to keep the indexing in the two independent arrays synchronized with the number of items gets large.

Answer (score 0):

If your capital array index are equal to country names for example

```
var country={"USA","Greece","Germany"};
var Capitals={"DC","Athens","Berlin"};
```

what i mean by equal are that country and that country capital index are the same
then you can generate number `var Number=new Random().Next(0,5);`
ant print like this: `Console.WriteLine("Country: {0} Capital:{1}",country[Number],Capitals[Number]);`
How ever if you can't gurantee that indexes will be at the same position then i suggest use class.

```
public class CountryWithCapital
{
  publict string Country {get;set;}
  public string Capital {get;set;}
  public CountryWithCapital(){}//Empty default constructor 
  public CountryWithCapital(string Country, string Capital)
  {
    this.Country=Country;
    this.Capital=Capital;
  }
}

//Implementation.
var CountriesWithCapitals=new List<CountryWithCapital>();
CountriesWithCapitals.Add(new CountryWithCapital("here is your country","this is your capital")); //Repeat this n times you want.
var Number=new Random().Next(0,5);
Console.WriteLine("Country :{0}, Capital :{1}",CountriesWithCapitals[Number].Countrry, CountriesWithCapitals[Number].Capital);
```